# adplus unable to create second chance dump file

Tags: windbg, adplus

I run adplus using below to monitor MyProcess and create dump file on crash.

```
"adplus -crash -pn MyProcess -o c:\temp"
```

But second chance dump file creation fails with below error.

```
"Unable to create file 'c:\temp\20180503_023959_Crash_Mode\FULLDUMP_SecondChance_*_UnknownException_MyProcess.exe__8c40_2018-05-03_02-45-05-535_8b24.dmp' - Win32 error 0n123
    "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.""
```

I think `*`(star) in file name is resulting in this. It could be due to `*` in unknown exception itself. Below are exception details from log.

> "(8b24.75d8): Unknown exception - code c0000374 (!!! second chance
>   !!!) SecondChance_*_UnknownException"

Does anyone know if there is a way to get dump file generated in such scenarios? Thanks

Comment: `0n123` is `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` so the `*` is probably the culprit. Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to customize only the dump file name used by adplus. As a workaround, you can try another tool like [procdump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump) with the command line: `procdump -e -ma MyProcess`. [DebugDiag](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/debugdiag/) allows you to monitor for crashes as well, but its a much heavier install than adplus or procdump.

Comment: configure [Windows Error Reporting service to generate dumps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: does WER work? Do you gets dumps?